# issues in adding compression to unix filesystem

Tags: filesystems, compression

I am revising for an Operating Systems course and one of the questions in a past paper is as follows:

```
Some modern Unix filesystems support file-system internal compression.
That is, a file can be flagged so that within the filesystem, the file’s data
is compressed, although reading and writing to the file appears as normal
to users of the filesystem. What issues would you expect to have to be
addressed in adding compression to a traditional Unix filesystem?
```

I can't think of any issues which would need to be addressed. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains the very issue that needs to be addressed initially-"although reading and writing to the file appears as normal to users of the filesystem".i.e the compression has to be *transparent*. Another factor could be the compression algorithm used which has to be fast enough so as not to introduce too much of a delay in compressing/decompressing the files during I/O.